# Touch Down on Layout Blocking Other Touch Events of Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, ontouchlistener, touch-event, android-imagebutton

I'm implementing tap events on several ImageButtons and code looks like this

```
  MyTouchListener touchListener = new MyTouchListener();
        l1.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        r1.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        l2.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        r2.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

 public class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.l1:
                    clickL1(v);
                    break;
                case R.id.r1:
                    clickR1(v);
                    break;
                case R.id.l2:
                    clickL2(v);
                    break;
                case R.id.r2:
                    clickR2(v);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
   }
```

Problem I have encountered is when I hold one finger on layout (anywhere EXCEPT on imagebuttons), the buttons do not register any events while I hold it.

I tried giving my layout its own touch listener that returns false but that didnt work.

What should I do to "disregard" touch down event on layout and just listen normally to imagebutton events?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:splitMotionEvents="true"
    tools:context="com.example.josip.something.GameOffline">


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/l1"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/r2"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>


<RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your xml

Comment: @KirillK There :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution doing this. I put another RelativeLayout as a child of main Layout and as a sibiling of buttons. I made it clickable and this way it works when I hold finger on layout anywhere except the buttons and I try clicking buttons, the event triggers. Why is that, I dont know and if someone does I would like an explanation.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:splitMotionEvents="true"
    tools:context="com.example.josip.something.GameOffline">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:clickable="true"></RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/l1"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/r2"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>


<RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Set `android:splitMotionEvents="true"` in the layout containing buttons.

Instead of `event.getAction()` try `MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event)` to get action associated with the correct pointer index. Read more about it here: [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html)

And you should return `true` only if you really handled an event, which is inside `if { }` statement. Otherwise return `false`

Comment: Using example you provided I figured out that while I hold finger on layout and try to touch button, the event DOES register (as a multiple event) but touch is simply not propageted to button..Any idea how to change that?

Comment: interesting point. try setting `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` or play with similar properties in xml (or `button.setFocusableInTouchMode`)

Comment: Another possibility is to try to use `TouchDelegate` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html  that will get touch events and perform clicks on the buttons instead of adding OnTouchEventListeners directly

Comment: @user6754277 see my answer edit, this time I hope it will help

Comment: Still not working :/ . I tried even clearing focus from Layout and setfocus on one of the buttons. Basically, when i'm holding on layout, any other touch android interprets as touch on layout and not it's children

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `return` `true` inside `onTouch` to `false`.
By doing so you'll tell android to pass the event to the next handler (e.g `onClick`).

Comment: I actually did that is one try as suggested by @Kirill K but didn't work. My xml is now looking as suggested by my own answer and java is as represented in question. And it works, I just dont know exactly why